# calling containsKey on a hashmap with custom class

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Color class that I'm putting in the hashmap. I'd like to call `containsKey` on the hashmap to ensure whether the object is already present in the hashmap

Color class

```
public class Color {
  public String name;
  Color (String name) {this.name = name;}
  //getters setters for name 
}
```

HashMap

```
HashMap<Color, List<String>> m = new HashMap<Color, List<String>>();
Color c = new Color("red");
m.put(c, new ArrayList<String>());
Color c1 = new Color("red");
System.out.println(m.containsKey(c1)); //I'd like to return this as true
```

Since `c1` has `name` red. I'd like the `System.out` to return true because the key already present in the map, `c`, has `name` red

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your custom class `Color` should override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods to achieve what you want.

When you are using custom objects as keys for `collections` and would like to do **lookup using object**, then you should properly override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

**Also read:**

[Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)